# How to view the Polymerfire demo using Polymer’s `polymer serve` polyserve server?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit, firebase-polymer, polymer-cli

[I want to view this demo of Polymerfire in my browser](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/tree/master/demo).

I expect to see the demo run in my browser. Instead, I see a blank page and the following console error.

console.log.error.message

> GET http://localhost:8080/ 404 (Not Found)
>   Navigated to http://localhost:8080/

I used the following procedure:

1. [I installed the Polymer-CLI multi-tool per the instructions found here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli#install).
2. [I created a project using the Polymer Starter Kit (PSK)](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/).
3. I named the project `my-app`.
4. I installed the Github repo found here using the CLI:
   `bower install ---save firebase/polymerfire`
5. I opened the terminal and navigated to the app's root directory.
   `cd path/to/my-app`
6. [I ran the following Polymer-CLI command (per the instructions found here)](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli#serve).
   `polymer serve`

What can I do to try and solve this so I can see the demo run in my browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to run an elements demo is to check it out...

```
git clone https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire.git

cd polymerfire

bower install

polymer serve
```

I have never tried to run the demos from a bower install'd folder but, the above method will work.

Answer (score 4):

You also have to navigate to the correct localhost path:
`http://localhost:8080/components/polymerfire/demo/`

So the complete procedure (from the command line) is:

First, [install the polymer-cli per the instructions found here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli#install).

```
npm install -g bower
npm install -g polymer-cli
```

Then run the following.

shell.sh

```
git clone https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire.git
cd polymerfire
bower install
polymer serve
open http://localhost:8080/components/polymerfire/demo/
```