# How do I deploy the polymerfire demo to firebase?

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymerfire

I want to try the demo for [polymerfire](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire) in [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). To get it run locally I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37777277/505701). But what exact steps do I need to do to get it to run in firebase?

I figured `firebase init` and `firebase deploy` should be run but the browser only displays errors in the console. Must the polymer project be build in a certain way and what should the firebase "public" folder be?

Comment: If you get an error, show the error. In general it would be useful to see exactly the steps that you've taken. At worst we can use these to try and reproduce the problem, but maybe that is not even needed and we can immediately see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All files from *public* folder will be deployed to your Firebase static web hosting, so you can access them though your Firebase hosting address like `https://projectname-5gek53.firebaseapp.com/`. This allows you to upload your web app.

You build your polymer app (I guess you need to run `polymer build`). You drag all files generated as production build to your *public* folder. Next, you run `firebase deploy` and after deployment process your app will be accessible from your hosting address as I mentioned above.

Edit: Polymerfire demo is actually not that simple to export, but I found a really nice tutorial step-by-step from Google Codelabs here is a link [Build a Progressive Web App with Firebase, Polymerfire and Polymer Components](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/polymer-firebase-pwa/index.html)

Comment: The tutorial is good. I've begun to follow it and have put the export aside.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed a new version of the polymer cli and Firebase cli.  When I do a Polymer build, no build/bundled or build/unbundled is created.
I do get a build/default, which I can run with a firebase serve and a firebase deploy. So something has changed recently.  just fyi